# How to access Shadow Dom in Intern / Leadfoot

Tags: javascript, testing, polymer, intern

I'm trying to do functional tests for a `Google Polymer` project using `InternJS`.

The `Web-Components` part looks like the following:

```
<custom-element-one flex> 
    <custom-nested-element id="someId">
    </custom-nested-element>
</custom-element-one>
```

The problem is that I can not access the `Shadow DOM` within the tests:

```
return this.remote
.get(require.toUrl('http://localhost:8500/test.html'))
.then(pollUntil('return document.querySelector("custom-element-one").shadowRoot;', 20000))
.findByTagName('custom-element-one')
.getProperty('shadowRoot')
.then(function (doc) {
    console.log('1--------------------->>>>', doc);
    console.log('2--------------------->>>>', doc.findByTagName('custom-nested-element'));

    doc.findByTagName('custom-nested-element')
        .getAttribute('id')
        .then(function (doc) {
            console.log('3--------------------->>>>', doc);
        });
});
```

### Results:

First log returns the following:

```
1--------------------->>>> { _elementId: '8',
_session:
{ _sessionId: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx',
_server:
{ url: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/',
sessionConstructor: [Function: ProxiedSession] },
_capabilities:
{ applicationCacheEnabled: false, ...

2--------------------->>>> { cancel: [Function], then: [Function] }


Object #<Promise> has no method 'getAttribute'
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

My guess is that `shadowRoot` is not part of the `leadFoot` library yet and it is not possible to access the shadow DOM on nested

Comment: I have not tested it. Web Component Tester uses Polymer.whenReady() to wait till polymer has done all its microtasks. May be you can try it out. I have internjs on my to learn list still

Comment: Intern's `pollUntil` is the equivalent of that. It waits till the element is ready in DOM.  The element is ready in DOM, it s just not accessible because of shadowRoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly the WebDriver issue rather than anything else. Support of Shadow DOM is very limited in WebDriver. ([more](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22987)).

But as a work around this, you could use `pollUntil` to grab the element and then get any of its attributes or call any of its exposed methods.

It would be similar to this, if you want to test value of the `id` attribute:

```
return this.remote
.get(require.toUrl('http://localhost:8500/test.html'))
.then(pollUntil(function () {
    if (document.querySelector('custom-element-one').shadowRoot) {
        return document.querySelector('custom-element-one').shadowRoot.querySelector('custom-nested-element').id;
    }
    return null;
}, [] , 20000))
.then(function (idValue) {
    assert.equal(idValue, 'someId');
});
```

Comment: For future references I documented my experience here: http://mmxgroup.net/2014/12/16/testing-a-google-polymer-project-using-internjs/